# iTextSharp : document with age portrait and landscape

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting, itext

I'd like to have a a document, the first page "Portrait" and the other (added by `NewPage();`) landscape. Is it possible ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `Document` object's [SetPageSize()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html#setPageSize%28com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle%29) method:

```
document.Open();
document.Add(new Paragraph("Page 1: PORTRAIT"));
document.SetPageSize(new Rectangle(842, 595)); // A4
document.NewPage();
document.Add(new Paragraph("Page 2: LANDSCAPE"));
```

Comment: 792, 612 it's for A4 ? not possible to use predefined value A4 ?

Comment: The `iTextSharp.text.PageSize` class has a bunch of pre-defined rectangles that you can use including `PageSize.A4` and `PageSize.A4_LANDSCAPE`. Use these whenever setting a `PageSize` instead of the regular numbers.

Comment: You can use any of the static members if page rotation is **NOT** important. `PageSize.A4_LANDSCAPE` calls an overloaded `Rectangle` constructor with a page rotation of 90 degrees. (it's been that way for a while) Check the `PageSize` source for all the values.

Comment: Sorry but without the Rotate the page is portrait

Comment: Are you using an older version? Tested w/5.1.2.0 it works for me; `new Rectangle(842, 595));`. Anyway, glad things worked out for you.